# In php why is it the case that 10 & 10 == 10 returns 0?

Tags: php, operators

I am messing with PHP operators and I cannot understand why

```
10 & 10 == 10
```

returns 0.
This should compare 10 to 10 which is true right?

Comment: Associativity `(10&10)==10` ?

Comment: returnees nothing, is not valid php

Comment: @elclanrs actually, in PHP the [equivalency comes before the bitwise](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comparison operators have [higher precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) than the bitwise operators, so that expression is evaluated as:

```
10 & (10 == 10)
```

`10 == 10` evaluates to true, so you get `10 & true`.
The bitwise `&` converts the `true` to `1`, so you get `10 & 1` which is `0`.

Notice that `11 & 10 == 10` results in `1`, since `11 & 1 === 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `==` operator is parsed before the `&` operator because it is judged more important by the parser. But you can override the default operator evaluation order with brackets:

```
(10 & 10) == 10
```

Comment: @TiLoup This answer is actually incorrect. [Paulpro](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25070063/436282) has it right.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression is similar to:

```
( 10 & 10 == 10 ) = ( 10 & (10 == 10) ) = ( 10 & (true) ) = 0
```

Precedence of `==` is from right (higher) it will be evaluated before `&`

Answer (score 1):

& is used for bit operations and == for comparison so be careful ... 
Here is an example :

```
echo((10 & 12));
```

Is printing 8 because 10 = 00001010 and 12 = 00001100 and 00001010 & 00001100 = 00001000 = 8

Answer (score 1):

Are you comparing if 10 is the same as 10?

```
IF (10 == 10) {
     // condition code
}
```

or 10 and 10 are both true

```
IF (10 && 10) {
    // condition code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

& is the bitwise operator in php and == tests for equality.

Since the precedence, see http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php, of == is higher than &, your test is the same as 10 & (10 == 10)

10 == 10 will return boolean true (same as a 1 in binary)

Now we are left with 10 & true which is the same as 10 & 1

the bitwise operator, &, looks at each bit of the 2 values and sets the corresponding bit in the result to 1 if they are both 1 and 0 otherwise, e.g.:

```
5 (101) & 3 (011) = 1 (001)
5 (101) & 2 (010) = 0 (000)
6 (110) & 4 (100) = 4 (100)
```

Therefore 10 (1010) & 1 (0001) = 0 (0000) so the result of 10 & 10 == 10 is 0!

If you just want to compare 10 to 10 then use 10 == 10